# Olá Mundo no React.JS não funciona!

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando printar um "Olá Mundo!" no React.JS

Vejam meu código, simplesmente não funciona:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="library/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="library/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="library/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="root"></div>


    <script type="text/babel">

        var React    = require('react');
        var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


        ReactDOM.render(
          <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
          document.getElementById('root')
        );

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Já tentei várias vezes, nunca funciona! O que há de errado aí!?!?

Comment: o react.js está mesmo nessa pasta library?

Comment: Puxa os arquivos da CDN, se funcionar é pq o caminho aí dos arquivos estão errados.

Comment: Não, não! O caminho está certo. Os arquivos .js estão armazenados na library sim. Nem por CDN esse tal de React não funciona! Já tentei assim também!

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o erro esteja no `Babel`, ele é um pré processador de `javascript`, não acredito que se possa usá-lo via `cdn`, ele deve ser configurado internamente, no `snippet` do `jsfiddle` é possível habilitar o `Babel`, veja funcionando...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>
```